# What is the difference between Capitalization Rate and Return on Assets?

Tags: real-estate, calculation, rental-property, terminology, rate-of-return

In real estate, the *capitalization rate* (cap rate) is one of the metrics used to assess the rental profitability of a property. The formula for capitalization rate is net operating income divided by market value of the real estate. How does *capitalization rate* differ from *return on assets* (ROA)? Both metrics seem to be calculated in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the general formula is the same, but they are used in different contexts. Cap Rate is a term that's more specific to real estate and generally applies to specific properties, or groups of similar properties (e.g. properties in this area have an average cap rate of X). Return On Assets is a more general term that can apply to any company and typically uses the total assets of the entire company, of segments of a company, rather then specific assets or groups of assets.